# For Updating user profile in Azure through MS Graph, do i have to be global admin?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to update user profile using MS Graph.

Scopes: All are delegated permissions :  "scp": "Directory.AccessAsUser.All Directory.Read.All Directory.ReadWrite.All Group.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All User.Invite.All User.Read User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite User.ReadWrite.All"

My Directory role is : Application administrator, Application developer.

Error I am getting: "Authorization_requestDenied . Insufficient privileges to complete the operation".

Inspite of having all permissions , why I am still getting this error , is it because I am not a global administrator ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update user using MS Graph, you need the related permissions in the following:

[image]

When updating the password Profile property, the following permission is required: Directory.AccessAsUser.All.

For details, you can refer to this [docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_update)

Comment: Hi , thank you for response. Well those are the permissions required to perform that operation by MS Graph API and i already have those permissions. I listed scopes in the question. Inspite of having these permissions it was not working.

Comment: You already have these permissions, and also grant these permissions for MS Graph? Since you are using MS Graph, you need to grant application permission for Microsoft Graph.

Comment: And you need to know about the application administrator and application developer.

Comment: Application administrator: can create and manage all aspects of app registrations and enterprise apps; application developer: can create application registrations independent of the 'Users can register application' setting.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. but i was able to resolve it.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to post the solution for this , in case anyone encountered same scenario.

1. The Graph I am trying to use is by user  impersonation. So because it was acting on user behalf i have to give only delegated permissions.
2. Once delegated permissions are given, the user signing in should have user administrator role to edit profiles.
   Ensure you have user administrator role.

Hope it helps !